# Delete selected tables from Postgres sql

Tags: postgresql

I need to remove selected tables from the **Postgres SQL**. It would better to use `like` or `where` clause.

Like I have

```
TABLE_A
TABLE_B
TABLE_C
-
-
-
TABLE_N
```

I need to delete

```
TABLE_A to TABLE_X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
   r RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT oid::REGCLASS table_name
             FROM pg_class
             WHERE relname <= 'table_x'
             AND relkind = 'r'
    LOOP
          EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE' || r.table_name;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "c"

Comment: Sorry, I use it with more parameters

Answer (score 2):

Can be done with a single command, which is faster - in case this is a recurring task.

Add `IF EXISTS` if the existence of any tables is uncertain. This way we save an extra trip to the system catalogs (`information_schema.tables` or `pg_catalog.pg_tables`).
And you may want to add `CASCADE`:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
  -- child safety device: quote RAISE instead of EXECUTE to prime the bomb
  -- EXECUTE (
  RAISE NOTICE '%', (
     SELECT 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS'
         || string_agg('table_' || chr(ascii('a') + g) , ', ')
         || ' CASCADE;'
     FROM   generate_series(0,13) g
     );
END
$do$;
```

Generates a command of the form:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a, table_b, ... , table_n CASCADE;
```

Using `generate_series()` to generate requested table names. More here:

- [How to drop many (but not all) tables in one fell swoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490249/how-to-drop-many-but-not-all-tables-in-one-fell-swoop/22491284#22491284)
- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)